# Building/Compiling source in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, compilation, autotools, automake

I have an open source repository in my Ubuntu development machine.

The issue is that I am not able to compile the source code.

I have tried `./configure` and it failed. I could see that the directory does not have an executable `configure`.

On the other hand, the directory contains a `configure.ac` file.

Similarly the directory also contains a file `Makefile.am`.

Can somebody assist me in building the source code and generating a library out of it which can be used in other code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11071325/986760

Answer (score 0):

These files are used with the Autotools suite. Makefile.am files are compiled to Makefiles using automake.

Here are the steps to compile the code:

1. Configure

   ```
   ./configure
   ```

If that had issues, then try:

```
autoreconf
```

2. builds (compile) the source code:

   ```
   make
   ```
3. and optionally, to install:

   ```
   sudo make install
   ```

(or `su -c "make install"`)